# NameError: name 'Thread' is not defined when using "from threading import *"

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm using 'from threading import *' while learning about threading from this youtube link (takes you directly to 1:43 mark where the example is used)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W90hCBN_Qvg&t=103s&ab_channel=Simplilearn

The code is below

```
from threading import *
def show():
    print("This is a child thread")
t=Thread(target= show())
t.start()
print("This is the parent thread")
```

However, when I run this exact code on my latest pycharm (as of June 2023), I get this error: `NameError: name 'Thread' is not defined`

Could anyone suggest an alternative? I've been googling for answers and finally decide to create this post. Thanks-in-advance!

from threading import * to run successfully and get the same result as in the youtube tutorial

Comment: What is the output of `import threading; print(threading.__file__)`?

Comment: I'm going to guess that you have a file of your own named `threading.py`.

Comment: Update: I closed my PyCharm and reopened it, created a fresh project with a new python file and copy-pasted this code, and it worked just like in the tutorial. Thanks all!